# sweetalert2 bloquea toda la pantalla

Tags: sweetalert2

estoy comenzando a utilizar sweetalert2 y bloquea todo... no lo hace constantemente pero si muy seguido.
Adjunto una imagen de la ispeccion[image]
bloquea todo es que hay un panel transparente que al hacer click sobre cualquier botón no hace nada... la única alternativa para continuar es tocando F5. ejemplo mínimo no se como replicar este problema por que me lo genera sweetalert.. tal vez desactivando algo del modal se solucione... pero bueno intente ver que podía ser pero realmente no conozco mucho de sweetAlert... y necesito resolver rápido desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: bloquea todo es que hay un panel transparente que al hacer click sobre cualquier botón no hace nada... la única alternativa para continuar es tocando F5. ejemplo mínimo no se como replicar este problema por que me lo genera sweetalert.. tal vez desactivando algo del modal se solucione... pero bueno muchas gracias seguire investigando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré la solución:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613677/div-swal2-container-is-still-visible-after-using-swal2-with-redirect-and-going

Saludos espero les sea de ayuda como a mí.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el contenido esencial del enlace _en la respuesta misma_. Piénsalo: si el enlace llega a caer, y un lector más adelante tiene un problema similar, ¿cómo sabrá qué contenía el enlace? Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.